# Recommended settings for the magic unicorn primitive?

Tags: mesh

I'm having trouble to figure out meaningful parameter settings for the unicorn primitive operator.

It's mainly about the hoofs:

- should I make them two-toed or four?
- Is a [**head-to-toe**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytpyUtySQG0) ratio of 3:1 realistic?
- there is no option to add nail polish, can anyone share a node setup for pink glitter, but also a decent subsurface scattering?

Bonus question: How many horn spins do you like the most?

[image: Unicorn Mesh Primitive]

Comment: It needs to spew real, 24k gold Unicoins out of my monitor for the effect to REALLY be pleasing. (LOTS of them!)

Comment: Also, can you have controls so the enthralled eyes & lolling tongue could be added for special occasions?

Comment: @Vader VADER VADER VADER VADER VADER VADER play along!
:D

Comment: @vader I vote YOU come up with the pink glitter nail polish node tree.

Comment: I vote to close because "Closed because unicorns"

Comment: I already wasted all my unicoins so I can't CV it

Comment: @ThomBlairIII I am working on it ;)

Comment: @CoDEmanX LoL, nice one! Still searching for the button tho :(.. The icon looks better than the real thing!

Comment: What the.. Suzanne got some competition.

Comment: So, is this on BlendSwap yet?!

Comment: Closed because unicorns...

This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a real question. It was a Apirl first joke, and there is no unicorn primitive operator in blender.

Comment: *FYI:* [Italian wildlife reserve officials find real-life Unicorn Deer!](http://www.nbcnews.com/id/25097986/ns/technology_and_science-science/t/unicorn-deer-found-italian-preserve/#.U2U1UOZdUeM)

Comment: If this question isn't reopened and the rights of Unicorn primitives upheld, I may be forced to notify GreenPeace & the NAAU (the National Association for the Advancement of Unicorns)!

Comment: If moderators refuse to help us, as a last resort, I may be forced to even involve Redfoo. He is a known champion of [causes such as this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1w9DiGlZksU&feature=kp). ***#ReopenBecauseOfRedfoo***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a nail polish shader you can use. I am no make-up artist but I believe it should looks something like this. It does not use SSS but it does render on the GPU.

[image]

Node Setup

[image]

Comment: AWESOME! Can you make it sparkle more? Maybe even rainbow colored sparkles??!
:D

Comment: @ThomBlairIII I updated the material

Comment: Aww Yeah!! That's what I'm talkin about! :D

Comment: My Little Pony & Hasbro would be proud!

Comment: @ThomBlairIII I am not familiar with that franchise

Comment: OMG! Take a [look](https://www.google.com/search?q=my+little+pony&num=100&safe=off&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS511US512&espv=210&es_sm=119&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=wkI7U_HqOfPHsASB6oDICw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1077&bih=583)!