# Suspended glitter in clear material

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I've been hunting for a bit with no real results for a material that looks like glitter cast in resin or clear nail polish with glitter floating inside of it. There's plenty of results for solid glitter materials like flecks seen mostly on cars but when I try to tweak them to my liking I can't seem to get the results I'm looking for.

[image]

[image][image][image]

Here are examples of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Possible duplicate of :[how tocreate a glitter texture](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45358/how-to-create-a-glitter-texture)

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99251/cycles-material-a-kind-of-glitter and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8230/recommended-settings-for-the-magic-unicorn-primitive and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116863/how-would-you-approach-a-shader-for-a-glittery-eyeshadow/116870#116870

Comment: If you want the look in 2nd image it's easiest to model the flakes. Create some particle flakes randomly distributed inside the volume. While possible shader like that would be extremely complicated and would probably render slowly.