# How to make the glittery effect cleaner on cycles render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, noise-reduction

I´m finishing this study but I think the gliterry party is a little off, kinda blurry. Does anyone have any tip on how to improve it this final render? Thanks a lot!

[image]

[image]

I mean this part (the upload here made the image low quality somehow):
[image]

Doesn´t look sharp like this glitter image:
[image]

Comment: are you asking for critique, or is there a specific question about your project? As your question is currently written, it seems subjective and slightly opinion based, and these types of questions generally need to be edited and clarified to be received well and have good answers for them. Please [edit] your question and add a bit more detail of what it is you are having trouble with. Thanks :)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144441 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116863 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8230 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/99251 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45358